# Displaying Error Message in CodeIgniter 4

Tags: php, forms, validation, view, controller

I am humbly seeking a help on how to go about displaying error message in CI4. i have create a controller like this:

```
public function login()
{
    $validation = \config\services::validation();

    $errors  = array('email' => 'bad email',
                'pass' => 'bad pass '); 


    if(!$this->validate(array('email' => 'required',
                         'pass' => 'required')))
    {
        echo view('login', array('validation' => $this->validator));
    }
    else
    {
        print 'success';
    }
}
```

while a tested each of the error reporting function below:

```
$validation->listErrors();
$validation->listErrors('list');
$validation->showError();
$validation->showError('sigle');
$validation->showError('email');
```

but non of these function work, if i entered correct data it print success as assign but upon wrong data it all show the same error message which is:

1. Call to a member function listErrors() on null.
2. Call to a memberfunction listErrors() on null.
3. Call to a member function showError()on null.
4. Call to a member function ShowError() on null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

call form helper in your controller before your validation start

```
 helper('form');
```

and i re-arrange ur code like this

```
public function login()
    {
        $data = [
            'validation' => \config\services::validation()
        ];

        if ($this->request->getMethod() == "post") { // if the form request method is post
            helper('form');
            $rules = [
                'email' => [
                    'rules' => 'required',
                    'errors' => [
                        'required' => 'bad email'
                    ]
                ],
                'pass' => [
                    'rules' => 'required',
                    'errors' => [
                        'required' => 'bad pass'
                    ]
                ]
            ];

            if (!$this->validate($rules)) {
                echo view('login', array('validation' => $this->validator));
            } else {
                // whatever you want todo 
            }
        }

        echo view('login', $data);
    }
```

in your login view, if you want to call all error list you got use this method `$validation->listErrors();`

if you want to call a specific error use this method `$validation->listErrors('email');`

if you want to check is the specific field returning an error use this method `$validation->hasError('email'))`

i hope this help you to solve your problem